# FOSUserBundle unlock user on login: changes are not persisted

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I have locked users that can re-activate their account if they enter a valid `ValidationCode` on login. As the user is previously locked, I use `AuthenticationFailureListener` to detect the login failure and determine if there is a valid validation code, according to log tracing every action seems to have correct data and everything should work ok but the problem is the **data remains the same, nothing is persisted in database**, so no change occurs.

This is my code:

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $userReactivated = false;

    // Checks if error is due to user locked and 
    if ( $exception instanceof LockedException )
    {
        $username = $request->request->get("_username");
        $v_code = $request->request->get("_validation_code");

        error_log("{$username} {$v_code}");

        $user = $this->em->getRepository("AppUserBundle:Usuario")->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
        if ($user != null)
        {
            $validationCode = $this->em->getRepository("AppUserBundle:ValidationCode")->findOneBy(array('code' => $v_code));

            if ($validationCode != null)
            {
                error_log("Code " . $validationCode->getId());
                if ($validationCode->isActive())
                {
                    $user->setValidationCode($validationCode);
                    $userReactivated = true;

                    $user->setLocked(false);
                    $this->em->persist($user);
                    $this->em->flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$userReactivated)
        return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
    else
    {
        return true; // TODO: login user and redirect to home page
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!$userReactivated) {
    $exception->setUser($user);
    return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
} else {
    return true; // TODO: login user and redirect to home page
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".